# Containerized Springboot Application - Loading an Embedded Keystore (.jks/.p12) from within the JAR

Tags: spring-boot, docker, ssl, kubernetes, keystore

Background: I have a springboot app that is containerized using docker and runs on a kubernetes cluster. It performs API calls, and relies on an SSLContext that requires loading a .jks truststore, like so:

```java
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(ResourceUtils.getFile(keyStoreFilePath),
                        keyStorePassword.toCharArray(), new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();
```

Note that the String keyStoreFilePath is currently injected as an environment/property variable at release time, and points to a location like /etc/ssl/keystore.jks on the host machine that runs a container. The disadvantage is that I have to resort to mounting this as a persistent volume in kubernetes for my containerized application to access it.

Instead, I decided to embed it into the application's classpath so that our operations team don't have to setting it up in all the host machines. But when I do, by specifying the keyStoreFilePath value like so: `classpath:security/keystore.jks`, it runs fine when I run the project in Eclipse/STS. But it fails with the error below inside the container:

`class path resource [security/cacerts] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/security/cacerts","stackTrace":"org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:217)`

Again, what is interesting is that the exact same thing runs just fine in Eclipse, but fails inside the container. Any pointers?

**Update:** verified the keystore.jks file is < 1 MB in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. Since the keystore.jks is embedded within the jar and needs to be loaded from the classpath (`classpath:security/keystore.jks`), we can not read it as a file. Instead, we will have to read it as an input stream - true for all resources within the jar file (classpath). So, I have to do something like this to get it to work:

```java
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keystore.load(truststoreResource.getInputStream(), keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(keystore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar) answer was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The error message shows `file:/<some-path-in-the-container>/App.jar!/keystore.jks` - no "security" folder whereas the value passed in for `keyStoreFilePath` is `classpath:security/keystore.jks`?

It is unlikely that the JKS file is bigger than 1MB, which is the limit in Kubernetes for ConfigMap-s and Secrets, so an option is to create a [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) with the JKS file and mount a volume from the Secret - no need to use a persistent volume or [`hostPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) volume.

HTH

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo while masking the path shown in the error for the keystore in the container - I reproduced the error and updated the question with the exact error - the "security" does exist. And the keystore is < 1MB. So I think something else is going on ... I will find out and update